# Unexpected tokens I'm following a tutorial and we do really the same code but the video was published on 2018

Tags: kotlin

Log.d(tag:"MainActivity", msg:"Email is: " + email)
Log.d(tag:"MainActivity", msg:"Password: $password")

Comment: Please narrow the problem down and don't just dump your code and error here.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.d("MainActivity", "Email is: $email"); 
Log.d("MainActivity", "Password: $password")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you copied the so-called "Parameter Hints" by IntelliJ.
The parts of your code that end with a double-colon (`tag:` and `msg:`) aren't really part of the Kotlin code. Instead, the IDE that the creator of the tutorial was using showed hints for the names of the parameters.

### Example

The function

```kotlin
fun add(a: Int, b: Int): Int { 
    return a + b 
}
```

has two parameters, the first called `a` and the second called `b`.

This means when calling this code from IntelliJ, the IDE will show the following hints to the user so that he knows what parameters he is entering:

[image: Paramter Hint Example]

You can identify these hints by looking at them accurately. They have a different font, are boxed, and have a different background-color. Please note that these hints **are not part of the Kotlin code and cannot be written in Kotlin**, that's where your Syntax Error comes from.

Have fun learning Kotlin!